# AIC & Cp Mallows method regression (32 variables)

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection, model-selection, aic

I am trying to make a variable selection using AIC & Cp Mallows methods.

For AIC:

```
require(leaps)
b <- regsubsets(time~radius_mean+texture_mean+perimeter_mean+area_mean+smoothness_mean+compactness_mean+concavity_mean+concave_points_mean+symmetry_mean+fractal_dimension_mean+radius_se+texture_se+perimeter_se+area_se+smoothness_se+compactness_se+concavity_se+concave_points_se+symmetry_se+fractal_dimension_se+radius_worst+texture_worst+perimeter_worst+area_worst+smoothness_worst+smoothness_worst+compactness_worst+concavity_worst+concave_points_worst+symmetry_worst+fractal_dimension_worst+tumor_size+lymph_node, datasetX)
rs<-summary(b)
rs$which
n<-nrow(datasetX[,3:35])
p<-ncol(datasetX[,3:35])
(AIC<-n*log(rs$rss/n)+(2:p))
plot(AIC~I(1:(p-1)),ylab="AIC",xlab="Number of Predictors")
```

The plot I get is:

[image]

The plot says that the minimum AIC is for 8 predictors that, looking at the which table, are perimeter_mean, area_mean, smoothness_mean, concave_points_mean, perimeter_se, area_se, smoothness_se and concave_points_worst.

Everything seems ok. But when I try to do the same for Cp Mallows criteria, I get:

```
plot(1:(p-1),rs$cp,xlab="Number of predictors",ylab="Cp Mallows")

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

That's true. The model has 32 variables and rs$cp is just 8. But I cannot understand why. Could you help me? Maybe am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance. Regards!

Comment: You may want to migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Scortchi I'm not sure about if the question is on-topic - because it arises from statistical problem, although the OP didn't notice that it had coding causes - but if it is off-topic it should be migrated, not put on hold.

Comment: @Pere: I can't see a statistical question in there at all. The reason I put it on hold is that Stack Overflow don't like us to migrate questions that they then have to close, & this one lacks a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), making it hard to answer conclusively. But because your answer seems very convincing, I tried just now to migrate the post, only to find the OP is blocked from asking questions on Stack Overflow. So it's stuck here, closed - sorry!.

Comment: Some of the general comments in your earlier thread apply here too. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257439/check-transformations-over-variables-in-model

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `regsubsets` checks by default models with just up to a few predictors - something about 8 predictors. Therefore, rs\$rss and rs\$cp length is 8, but 1:(p-1) is longer. That prompts the error message and triggers [vector recycling](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-art-of/9781593273842/ch02s03.html), that causes the pattern we can see in the graph.

You can check in-program help for `regsubsets` to adjust the maximum number of predictors (but beware that with large numbers of predictors it may take a long time or just crash), or you can adjust the *plot* order just to plot values from the models actually adjusted by `regsubsets`. Whatever action that makes the two vectors be of the same length may avoid that error.

BTW: my master's students at UOC are solving this same problem with the same dataset and some of them are finding the same error when using a code just like yours copied from an example problem with less than 10 predictors. Nice to meet you here.